# sizeof(array) in C: segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays

Hi i get a weird segmentation fault from this code:

```
int main(void){

  int array1[10000000];

  int n = sizeof(array1);

  printf("%d \n", n );

    return 0;
}
```

However if i change

```
int array1[10000000];
```

to

```
int array1[1000000];  ( one less zero)
```

The program works and prints 4000000

I'm running it on Fedora 21(64bits)

Is this because there is a maximum size for array in C?  Thank you in advance

Comment: The stack is typically a few megabytes, you simply cannot put a 38 mb array on it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
int array1[10000000];
```

is too large for your stack and you overflow your stack whereas

```
int array1[1000000];
```

is large, but does not overflow your stack as the array fits in it.

Note that the size of the stack can vary on different systems and can be set to a particular size.

Methods to solve it:

1. Make the array `static`.
2. Make the array global.
3. Allocate memory on the heap using `malloc` from `stdlib.h`:

   ```
   int *array1;
   array1 = malloc(10000000 * sizeof(int));

   if(array1 == NULL) /* If `malloc` failed to allocate memory */
   {
       fputs("Oops! `malloc` failed to allocate memory!\n", stderr);
       exit(-1); /* Exit the program with a return value of `-1` ; Requires `stdlib.h` */
   }

   /* Use the array and after use, free it using */

   free(array1);
   ```

Comment: OK thank you, but is there any way i can declare an array of size 10000000?

Comment: as the answer indicated, between functions, write 'static' (so only visible in this file) 'array1[10000000];'

Answer (score 2):

An additional method to solve it is to increase stack size with `setrlimit`. Standard size is 8 MB, at least on my Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

static int setstacksize(rlim_t stacksize)
{
    struct rlimit rl;
    int res;

    if ((res = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getrlimit result = %d, errno = %d\n", res, errno);
        return res;
    }
    if (rl.rlim_cur >= stacksize) return res;
    rl.rlim_cur = stacksize;
    if ((res = setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "setrlimit result = %d, errno = %d\n", res, errno);
    }
    return res;
}

static int func(void){

    int array1[10000000];
    int n = sizeof array1;

    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    setstacksize(48 * 1024 * 1024);
    func();
    return 0;
}
```